# Google Maps zoom level not registering

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I can get my google map to respond to zoom level changes. Below is the code but when I set the zoom to a different level and reload the map defaults to zoom level 9. I can't find anywhere else that i set zoom or change zoom on marker click. I feel like I'm missing something ridiculously obvious??

```
      // arrays to hold copies of the markers and html used by the side_bar 
      // because the function closure trick doesnt work there 
      var gmarkers = []; 

     // global "map" variable
      var map = null;
// A function to create the marker and set up the event window function 
function createMarker(latlng, name, html) {
    var contentString = html;
    var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
        position: latlng,
        icon: 'img/marker2_ltblue.png',
        map: map,
        suppressInfoWindows: true,
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5,
        labelContent: name,
        labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(75, 0),
        labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
        labelStyle: {opacity: 0.75}
        });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });

   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

     map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
     });

}

// This function picks up the click and opens the corresponding info window
function myclick(i) {
  google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], "click");
}

function initialize() {
  // create the map
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 7,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.369804, -106.388725),
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
    navigationControl: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                                myOptions);

 var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://www.huts.org/Gmaps/gpsTracks/10thsystemTrailsWinter.kml'
  });
  ctaLayer.setMap(map);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.close();
        });
      // Read the data from example.xml
      downloadUrl("gMapsHuts.xml", function(doc) {
        var xmlDoc = xmlParse(doc);
        var markers = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          // obtain the attribues of each marker
          var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
          var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("label");
          var html = GXml.value(markers[i].getElementsByTagName("infowindow")[0]);
          var category = markers[i].getAttribute("category");
          var season = markers[i].getAttribute("season");
          // create the marker
          var marker = createMarker(point,name,html,category);
        }

      });
    }

 // the important function... routes[id].xxxxx refers back to the top 



var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
  { 
    size: new google.maps.Size(175,175)
  });
```

Comment: Have you tried `map.setZoom(number)`?

Comment: Looks to me like you set it to 7 [zoom: 7], don't know why it would be 9.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the option `preserveViewport` of `ctaLayer` to `true`.

Otherwise the API will set to viewport of the map to an area that contains all the features of the layer(what in this case forces a zoom of 9)

Comment: that did it Dr. Molle. I thought of that at first but didn't realize the kml layers had default zoom levels. Thanks so much.

Comment: They don't have default zoom-levels, the zoom-level will depend on the size of the map and the bounds of the features in the particular layer .